# if and else if statements ignored, Javascript

Tags: javascript, if-statement

I have a purple button. It becomes green onclick, even if in the if statement instead of purple I wrote Yellow. 
Then it remains green, although the else if statement should make it purple again onclick. 
What's wrong with my code?

```
`var m = document.getElementById ("buttonanimation");
    function changecolor(){
        if (m.style.backgroundColor="yellow"){
        m.style.backgroundColor="green";
        } else if (m.style.backgroundColor="green"){
        m.style.backgroundColor="purple";
        }
    }`
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This symbol `=` is the *assignment*, not the *comparison*. `if (m.style.backgroundColor="yellow")` should be `if (m.style.backgroundColor === "yellow")`.

Answer (score 0):

use comparison operator if (m.style.backgroundColor==="yellow") instead of if (m.style.backgroundColor="yellow")